# regex querystring SSI

Tags: regex, apache, ssi

I have this URL:

```
http://www.xxxxxxxx.it/stagione.shtml#giornata_107
```

I tried to get number of giornata with regex like this:

```
<!--#set var="giornata" value="$QUERY_STRING = /\#giornata\_([0-9])/"-->
```

but I don't know the right syntax

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match ***one or more*** digits, using `[0-9]+` instead of just `[0-9]` which matches a ***single*** one:

```
<!--#set var="giornata" value="$QUERY_STRING = /\#giornata\_([0-9]+)/"-->
```

Comment: @hayden: No, it's used to mark the end of the `value` attribute.

Comment: My mistake, I read it as a backslash rather than a forward slash!